# Add a column in a PySpark Data Drame using a function

Tags: python, pyspark, calculated-columns

I'm trying to add a column in a PySpark DataFrame using a function I have defined before. The function is:

```
def is_company(name,cut):
    score = 0
    for i in name:
        if i in list:
            score =+ 1
        else:
            score = score
    if score >= cut:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

where "list" is a list containing the most common words in companies names.
Then, I have a data frame where one column are companies and people names and I apply the function in the column like this:

```
df_person.withColumn('is_empresa_col', is_company('apnomper',2))
```

I don't know why this doesn't work. The error is:

```
AssertionError: col should be Column
```

Comment: `if i in list`?

Comment: Imagine you have the name 'Carmen Perez', the you see if 'Carmen' is in the list of most common words in companies name (I didn't put this part of the programm completely because the problem is in the add column step)

Comment: The second argument of `withColumn` expects a Column expression.  I think you can turn your function into a `udf` to make that work.  `@pyspark.sql.functions.udf(returnType=pyspark.sql.types.BooleanType())` `def is_company...`

Comment: @0x5453 I also try that way:
    from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
is_company_udf = udf(is_company)
df_persona.withColumn('is_company_col', is_company_udf('apnomper',2))

Comment: This function will not work as UDF nor as above you have mentioned. After creating a udf, name argument in is_company gets a single name at a time. This function will then run on all records individually. Please be specific what you want in the additional column. Do you want score as a single value for the whole data or as individual different entries for each record? UDFs will accept only a single record at a time and return a value for each record.

Comment: @mayankagrawal I want to score as a individual different entries for each record. Do UDFs work in that case?

Comment: Yes UDFs will give individual different entries for each record, but they will take input only a single record at a time and work on your function on that particular name. You cannot give entire names column at once and iterate over it. But isn't your function supposed to give only one score for the entire data since you are iterating over all names in one go and finally returning 1 and 0?

Comment: @mayankagrawal No, I want to iterate in each record. I mean, for each record/name in the column, I want to see if  is_company = 1 or is_company = 0

Comment: I dont specifically understand why you would want that. Anyways, to make it work, remove the loop 'for i in name' as it will iterate over characters in a  string of name.Next create udf as you said before, import col from pyspark.sql.functions and pass the column as df_persona.withColumn('is_company_col', is_company_udf(col( 'apnomper'),2))